# Is there such a thing as a natural left outer join

Tags: sql

Practicing a sample exam for my dbms class and I ran across natural right outer join does such a join even exist?

Comment: Don't use `natural join` for anything, `left` or otherwise.  It uses columns that *happen* to have the same name, not even taking properly declared foreign key relationships into account.

Comment: Please ignore the question i realized the error in my ways:(

Comment: I'm really, really against natural joins. Though included in the syllabus they are very error prone, and their whole idea prevents encapsulation.